# Data in the Android Application to Kafka

Tags: android, apache-kafka

I want to create an app implementation with an Android studio and send the data collected on the app to Kafka.
But I don't have the exact information.

1. Can I create an app with an Android studio and send data to Kafka?
2. Can you tell me the big framework for how to make it?
   For example, an important grid used to send data to Kafka after collection.

There are a lot of questions because everything is new and I can't even set the direction.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, meaning that it helps you to code, it doesn't have any control over what is possible and what isn't possible, so your question doesn't involve the IDE, it just involves android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for REST APIs around Kafka for this purpose.

It does not look like you would be able to do that directly from app. Kafka receives data from publisher which is usually a backend service interfacing between your app and kafka endpoint that should receive data from all the apps and push those to kafka.

Otherwise, if you make every app a publisher, not sure if this will be supported by kafka and eventually will become difficult to maintain...

Comment: _not sure if this will be supported by kafka_ - Kafka doesn't care. The problem is that Android will have issues maintaining the TCP connection to the broker (which, like you said, is a backend service, and would need to be exposed to the open internet for mobile clients to work). Kafka also doesn't expose any REST endpoints itself

Comment: Ah then it makes sense...it is supposed to work as a backend worker task and onus is own exposed service to talk to kafka. also,  maintaing publisher connection is another bout of challenge on incosistent mobile application network.